# how to find cause of errors while data validation

Tags: clustering, pattern-recognition

I have two datasets, that should correspond to each other. But there are certain fields which contain errors, and I need to find trends in those errors found. For example, all data in column1 has errors when data in column 3 is between two dates/values. Or whenever the value in column4 has category 'x' there is error in column2. The problem is I am completely new to statistics, and 2nd problem is I would be unaware of the structure of my dataset. From what angle should I tackle this problem. Any help is much appreciated

```
name    amount     date    flag

ab       100    23/01/2017  1

ac       110    21/02/2017  2

ad       131    22/02/2017  1

ae       120    24/03/2017  2

af        60    25/06/2017  1

ag        45    21/02/2017  3


name    amount    date    flag

ab       100    23/01/2017  1

ac       100    21/02/2017  1

ad       121    22/02/2017  2

ae       120    24/03/2017  2

af        60    25/06/2017  1

ag        40    21/02/2017  3
```

We can see that amount is off in the table when the month is febraury, and most of the flags are off when date is february as well. Problem is I don't know the nature of tables, i will deal with, so I can't find a way to hardcode to find trends like this. How should I go about the same

P.s Getting tables in stack is a huge pain, if someone can format the same into tables to make the question clearer it would be much appreciated. https://senseful.github.io/ seems to be down for some reason. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Compare the tables. Mark errors.

Train a classifier to predict which cells will be marked.

If you use e.g. a decision tree, you may be lucky and end up with an interpretable tree.